# Is there a way to measure various metrics of Java code in SonarQube

Tags: java, parsing, sonarqube, metrics

I want to compute some complexity and quality metrics for java code in a custom SonarQube plugin. For these metrics various measures are needed like number of variables, operands, database-connections, functions and so on. SonarQube CoreMetrics provides only few of them and I don't want to build a complete java-file-parser to measure them by myself. So there are some questions about how to do that:

Is there a way to gather more of the needed values by SonarQube or an existing plugin, than available in CoreMetrics?

If not, does anybody knows a good opensource java-parser/scanner that measures a lot of size metrics out of source code which I can use in my project?

Thanks a lot for any advices and suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly the best way to achieve this is to try to implement some custom rule (see this [tutorial](http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/PLUG/Writing+Custom+Java+Rules+101) ).

You will implement a visitor on a parsed file and that will allow you to do any computation you want on the java code.

Comment: Thanks for your advice, but I don't want to define some coding rules to display them as bugs or code smells. I want to count various parameters in java source code like variables, methods and so on to compute some metrics out of them like Halsteads Complexity Metric for example. It seems to me that rules are not the right way to do that, because they only check if some constructs are in the code or not. Or am I wrong with that?

Comment: You have access to the parser and to an API to report issues. Just don't make use of the report issue API and use the parser to compute whatever metric you can think of.